# Passing Backbone Model attribute to Handlebars Helper

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

The Backbone model has the attribute "selectedYear". I need to pass this "selectedYear" attribute to Handlebars Custom Helper.

```
var sq2SelectCarYearModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "api/caryears",
    selectedYear: "0"


});
```

Here is what I have tried:
This is the handlebars templating:

```
template: Handlebars.compile("{{#times 27 this.model.attributes.selectedYear}}{{/times}}")
```

Handlebars Helper declaration:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(n, selectedYear, block) {
    // I need to use "this.model.attributes.selectedYear" here

});
```

PS: "times" is the name of the custom helper, "n" is the number of times a loop will run.

I also tried this:

```
template: Handlebars.compile("{{#times 27 selectedYear}}{{/times}}")
```

but it still doesnt work.

Comment: wondering whether the answers helped...!

Answer (score 1):

`selectedYear` is not an attribute on your model, but a property.

You can set it as a default by doing:

```
var CarModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'api/caryears',

  defaults: {
    selectedYear: 0
  }
});

var model = new CarModel()
// model.get('selectedYear') -> 0
```

you can also pass it in on instantiation

```
var model2 = new Model({ selectedYear: 2 });
// model2.get('selectedYear') -> 2
```

or you can set it after instantiation:

```
var model3 = new Model();
model3.set('selectedYear', 3);
// model3.get('selectedYear') -> 3
```

**EDIT**

To use the model attributes in a Backbone View I'd suggest doing something like the following

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model = new Model({
      selectedYear: 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile("{{#times 27 selectedYear}}{{/times}}");
    this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON));
  }
});
```

Backbone.Marionette does a lot of this for you - if you give a Marionette View a template, it will automatically pass in the models attributes so you don't need to provide a `render` method.

eg:

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile('your template here')
});

var model = new Model({selectedYear: 1});

var view = new view({model: model});

view.render();

// or region.show(view) which will automatically render the view.
```

Comment: thankyou, when i try to pass a parameter as a value to the handlebars, it works fine like: {{#times 27 '1993'}}{{/times}}, as you can see I passed "1993" as a parameter and I can use it in the Handlebars helper declaration but I need to pass in model.selectedYear instead to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `selectedYear` in model's `defaults`:

```
var sq2SelectCarYearModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "api/caryears",
  defaults: {
   selectedYear: "0"
  }
});
```

So that it'll be added to models `attributes` property. For setting it after creation, you should use `set()` method which will add the properties to models attribute hash.

right now, it's added as a direct property in model, `this.model.selectedYear` might work, but not the correct way to do it. Data should be added in models attributes hash so that other things like events work properly